# Event trigger using Mongo/Kafka

Tags: mongodb, events, apache-kafka

I've a mongoDB instance with a collection holding calendar events.  This is fed using a Kafka application.

These events need to feed into other downstream systems, using Kafka Streams, but what I'd like to invesitgate is whether is would be possible to only trigger an event to a downstream system when the event has just happened (rather then passing future events downstream).

So if an event is received and written to mongo for a date in the future, the downstream system will only know about it as that date is reached and not before.

I've looked at the normal connectors (mongoDB -> Kafka https://www.mongodb.com/kafka-connector) and that functionaility isn't provided.

One of the ways I thought about doing this would be to write a custom application which queries the mongo DB collection on a schedule between the "last run" and "now" to get all the events which occur within these times and create a downstream event into Kafka.  (setting indexes on the query elements in the mongo document).

Is there any other way?

Many thanks for reading.

Jill

Answer (score 0):

Instead of query the mongodb I would suggest to create a consumer group to the original kafka topic, which the mongodb data is ingested from and do if you recognize that the date is in the future -> create a rundeck / airflow scheduled task configured to that date, so your consumer logic will be simple.

Another solution you can try is to do some changes to the source connector that you found and try to merge it.

Good luck! Im here if you have any questions